# Update the last two digits of a varchar(22 BYTE)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to figure out how to change a list of numbers that end with 0230. How would I go about just changing only the last two digits.

Example:

```
254541563200222200230

Into :
254541563200222200228
```

Example2:

```
11154561560222200230

Into : 
11154561560222200228
```

I know the select command for finding values that end with those numbers just not how to update them since they all have different beginning numbers. They are all 22 digits in length.

```
SELECT * from data_table here data = '%0230'.
```

My best bet was this :

```
UPDATE data_table SET data = '%0229' where data = '%0230';
```

Answer (score 0):

`SUBSTR` can do that.

Your 2nd example is shorter than the 1st so I modified sample data a little bit; included `y` at the end to emphasize `0230` (i.e. the last 4 characters). The 3rd example shouldn't be modified at all as it doesn't end with `0230` (that's what `where` does).

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '2545415632002222y0230' from dual union all
  3     select 'x111545615602222y0230' from dual union all
  4     select '2412412412412412y1234' from dual
  5    )
  6  select col,
  7    substr(col, 1, length(col) - 2) || '28' result
  8  from test
  9  where substr(col, -4) = '0230';

COL
---------------------
RESULT
----------------------------------------------------------------
2545415632002222y0230
2545415632002222y0228

x111545615602222y0230
x111545615602222y0228


SQL>
```

---

As you're updating the column, then:

```
SQL> create table test as
  2    (select '2545415632002222y0230' col from dual union all
  3     select 'x111545615602222y0230'     from dual union all
  4     select '2412412412412412y1234'     from dual
  5    );

Table created.

SQL> update test set
  2    col = substr(col, 1, length(col) - 2) || '28'
  3  where substr(col, -4) = '0230';

2 rows updated.

SQL> select * From test;

COL
---------------------
2545415632002222y0228
x111545615602222y0228
2412412412412412y1234

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to figure out how to change a list of numbers that end with 0230.

The values are numbers (and you ought to store them as numbers rather than strings), you can use `MOD` to find the last 4 digits (provided they are all actually numbers, regardless of whether you've stored them as numbers or strings) and then just subtract one from the matching rows:

```sql
UPDATE data_table
SET data = data - 1
WHERE MOD( data, 10000 ) = 230;
```

So for your example data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE data_table ( data ) AS
SELECT '254541563200222200230' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '11154561560222200230' FROM DUAL;
```

Then after the update, the values would be:

```sql
SELECT * FROM DATA_TABLE;
```

> ```
> | DATA                  |
> | :-------------------- |
> | 254541563200222200229 |
> | 11154561560222200229  |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ff9ac8ca67461f1716987783e7b4a4df)*